# maths symbols are changed when compiling on arXiv

Tags: symbols, arxiv

The matrix and sum signs are changed when compiling on arXiv. 
It works well on TeXmaker with the packages:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}     
\usepackage{natbib}       
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{psfrag}
```

but on arXiv, I get the following:

[image]

Some brackets for matrices are not well typeset as well.
Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong there?

Comment: it's impossible to say anything given a list of packages and an image of some maths without any indication of its input, please post a small complete document that has the problem.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please could you provide not just a bit of preamble, but a full MWE: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that. That is, complete the preamble, add a `\begin{document}` and an `\end{document}` and the code you're using for that summation, at the least

Comment: How exactly are you previewing the result from arxiv? This kinda looks like a rendering error in a browser based pdf viewer.

Comment: I've seen that problem in browser embedded pdf readers. Download the pdf from the arxiv and check it in your usual pdf viewer